# :nth-child() odd/even pseudo classes with definition list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can't figure out how to apply the odd/even `:nth-child()` pseudo classes to definition lists

```
<dl>
    <dt>green foo</dt>
    <dd>green bar</dd>
    <dt>red foo</dt>
    <dd>red bar</dd>
    <dt>green foo</dt>
    <dd>green bar</dd>
</dl>

<style>
dl { color: blue }
dd:nth-child(odd) { color:green }
dd:nth-child(even) { color:red }​
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ge5h/2/

new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ge5h/7/

with the correct :nth-of-type pseudo class.

```
dd:nth-of-type(even) {color: red;}
dt:nth-of-type(even) {color: red;}
dd:nth-of-type(odd) {color: green;}
dt:nth-of-type(odd) {color: green;}
```

​

Comment: What's not working? All your `dd`s are even, so they're all red...

Comment: What do you want to "be different" between those items?

Comment: different color/background.  why are they all even? i want every other dd to change

Comment: Oh. You didn't say every other dt *and* dd. You need to be specific about these things or you won't get the right answers, only guesses...

Comment: fair enough. believe me i understand the importance of a good question is generating the correct answer.  i could've been more clear, but if i can get every other dd, then i can figure out every other dt.  it was the nth-of-type pseudo class that i was missing.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML, both `dt` and `dd` are siblings of one another, under the same parent `dl`. As such, if you're alternating between `dt` and `dd` in a single `dl`, then all your `dt` elements will be `:nth-child(odd)` while all your `dd` elements will be `:nth-child(even)`.

You're probably looking for `:nth-of-type()` instead, which will help you check only either the `dt` or `dd` type, unlike `:nth-child()` which doesn't care what kind of element it is, only its position relative to the parent.

If you want to make every odd `dd` green and every even `dd` red:

```css
dd:nth-of-type(odd) { color:green }
dd:nth-of-type(even) { color:red }​
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/8Ge5h/3)

Answer (score 0):

Note that from HTML 5.2 onwards it is allowed to have a "div as a child of a dl element."

So like this:

```
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Godzilla</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

And your css could be like:

```
dl { background-color: blue; padding: 10px }
div:nth-child(odd) { background-color:green }
div:nth-child(even) { background-color:red }
```